# I wanted to display only first div at a time and hide all other divs

Tags: typescript, angular

I wanted to display only first div at a time and hide all other divs. and on button click need to show second div and hide all all other divs.

Component template:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'question',
  template: `<div class="slide-{{question.id}}" [ngClass]="{hide: isOn}" *ngFor="let question of questions">
             <div class="section-head  text-center">{{question.heading}}</div>
             <div class="section-desc  text-center">{question.description}}</div>
             </div>

<div class="action">
   <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn prime prev-step ripple hide"><i class="material-icons pull-left">arrow_back</i> Prev </button>
       <button (click)="toggle(!isOn)" type="button" class="btn prime next-step ripple">Next <i class="material-icons pull-right">arrow_forward</i></button>
   </div>
</div>`
})
```

Class:

```
export class Question{
    id: number;
    heading: string;
    description: string;
    field: string;
    isOn = false;
    toggle(newState) {
        this.isOn = newState;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want.

I added an `i` variable for the index and then set `hidden` to true when the current index is not equal to the variable `showIdx`. On button click I increment the `showIdx` variable:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'question',
  template: `<div class="slide-{{question.id}}" [ngClass]="{hide: isOn}" *ngFor="let question of questions let i=index" [hidden]="i !== showIdx">
             <div class="section-head  text-center">{{question.heading}}</div>
             <div class="section-desc  text-center">{question.description}}</div>
             </div>

<div class="action">
   <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
       <button type="button" (click)="showIdx++" class="btn prime prev-step ripple hide"><i class="material-icons pull-left">arrow_back</i> Prev </button>
       <button (click)="toggle(!isOn)" type="button" class="btn prime next-step ripple">Next <i class="material-icons pull-right">arrow_forward</i></button>
   </div>
</div>`
})
```

```
export class Question{
    showIdx = 0;

    id: number;
    heading: string;
    description: string;
    field: string;
    isOn = false;
    toggle(newState) {
        this.isOn = newState;
    }
}
```

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer: Here on click compiler is not able to parse. So i am incrementing value like this (click)="increment(showIdx)" and on function increment(showIdx) {
        showIdx++;
    } .............but on a click of button the further divs are not showing

Comment: The function should be `increment() { this.showIdx++; }` or `(click)="showIdx = showIdx + 1" or maybe `(click)="showIdx+=1"`. I'm not sure what operators the template supports (sorry for this. I expected `++`) to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an object for `isOn` instead of a boolean. Here is a sample:

```
isOn: {}

toggle(question) {
  Object.keys(isOn).forEach(key => {
    if (key != question.id) {
      isOn[question.id] = false;
    }
  });
  isOn[question.id] = !isOn[question.id];
}
```

and in the template:

```
template: `
  <div class="slide-{{question.id}}"
       [ngClass]="{hide: isOn[question.id]}" 
       *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <div class="section-head  text-center">{{question.heading}}</div>
    <div class="section-desc  text-center">{question.description}}</div>

    <div class="action">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn prime prev-step ripple hide"><i class="material-icons pull-left">arrow_back</i> Prev </button>
      <button (click)="toggle(question)" type="button" class="btn prime next-step ripple">Next <i class="material-icons pull-right">arrow_forward</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`
```